# Running Hadoop 2.7.3 on Windows with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, hadoop

I'm trying to run Hadoop 2.7.3 on Windows 10 with Eclipse. 
I haven't set up an envierment variable for hadoop, because of Maven. In my pom.xml I only have hadoop-client dependency.

First I got:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

Then I downloaded the winutils.exe and hadoop.dll and put the in C:\winutiland\bin and added

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutil\\");
```

to my code.

Now i get

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
```

Isn't there really a simple way to run Hadoop with Maven/eclipse on Windows?

Answer (score -1):

Close  Eclipse, add the system variable HADOOP_HOME in your windows 10 System properties (HADOOP_HOME = "Your Hadoop dir")
Open Eclipse and execute the Java again

You could also read the solution described by Tushar Sarde in his post: http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/ ?

**Update:**
above link is expires, Please follow this link to Tushar's github repo, he has mentioned steps for the same
[Hadoop Installtion on Windows](https://github.com/sardetushar/hadooponwindowshttps://github.com/sardetushar/hadooponwindows)

Comment: Please update links , or the answer,